# weak definite article in Engish linguistics

Tags: terminology, articles, determiners, definiteness

I may be wrong, but I don't seem to have come across the term '**weak definite article**' in English linguistics though I think I've encountered it in German or French linguistics. (I've read '**weak definites**, referring to noun phrases with definite articles that does not allow you to uniquely identify the referents, but not '**weak definite articles**' in English linguistics)

Is it not used? Or, is it just me and my lack of experience? Any and all thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: By the term "English Linguistics" do you mean English _language_ or (maybe) _linguistic researches/ books on linguistics in English_ ?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak. I mean academics in the English linguistics field.

Comment: well, that was _recursive_ , you just mentioned the phrase again, is that _English language_ again?

Comment: It's linguistics on the English language ....

Comment: Then, if I may, it's an off-topic question pertaining to a specific language.

Comment: However, there's no harm in telling you that, unless there's been a recent bahnbrechende Erfindung at MIT, the term _weak article_ (definite or indefinite) is not used in linguistic descriptions of English. Or if it is, I haven't encountered it in 50+ years of being an English language linguist, so it isn't used much. Indeed, the only meaning I can put on it is the distinction between the two allomorphs of _the_: /ði/ before vowels and /ðə/ before consonants. But these are entirely phonological and don't depend on morphology at all, so calling one "weak" seems silly.

Comment: @jlawler. Thank you. What has puzzled me is like this: At the front desk of a hotel, the receptionist might say 'Go take the elevator to go to your room' while there are more than just one elevator there. Uniqueness proponents call the description weak definite because the box is not uniquely identified. They use 'weak definite description' but not 'weak definite article.' Well, this is becoming more unfitting for this forum. I will move to English Language & Usage. Thanks!!!

Comment: Those people are talking about philosophy, not English. Definite articles in English are often used in definite descriptions (which is a philosophical term, not a linguistic one), but they more often have nothing to do with unique identification. Indeed, some of their idiomatic uses (and practically all their uses are idiomatic, not semantic) are exact opposites of "unique identification", like _I dialed the wrong number_.

Comment: Much appreciated, jlawler. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

According to Cardinaletti & Starke 1999, there is in English:

Weak:

```
I see ya.
*I see ya and her.
```

Strong:

```
I see you.
I see you and her.
```

Comment: But the question is clearly about a distinction in semantics, not a distinction in phonetics or prosody, so this is not a helpful answer.

Comment: @ColinFine McWhorter argues for these phonetically reduced pronouns to be counted as separate morphemes (they cliticise readily) and there is a case to be made for a semantic distinction too

Comment: Either way, the question is about articles, not pronominals?

Comment: I agree with Wilson (esp. 2nd comment) My bad!